# tSQLt AssertEqualsTable support for the Geography data type

Tags: tsqlt

When I create two tables that contain a geography column and use 
tSQlt.AssertEqualsTable, the test fails with:

> failed: Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type
>   equals geography.{,1}

Does anyone know if tSQLt supports the geography data type for table comparisons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not supported but will be included in the next/future release.

Answer (score 2):

tSQLt has since been updated to include a more detailed error message for incompatible data types. If you use one of the incompatible data types you should see this message:

```
(Error) The table contains a datatype that is not supported for 
tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable. Please refer to http://tsqlt.org/user-
guide/assertions/assertequalstable/ for a list of unsupported datatypes.
```

The list of incompatible types are:

- XML
- Text
- NText
- Image
- Geography
- Geometry
- Rowversion
- Any CLR data type that is not marked as both Comparable and Byte Ordered

However, there is almost always a work-around. You can convert the value to a compatible data type before comparing it, as in the following example:

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'DeliveryTests';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DeliveryTests.[test Order is matched to Customer location]
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Sales.Customers';
  EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Sales.Orders';

  INSERT INTO Sales.Customers (CustomerId, Location) 
       VALUES (1, geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326));
  INSERT INTO Sales.Orders (OrderId, CustomerId) 
    VALUES (5, 1);

  SELECT OrderId, Location.ToString() AS Location
    INTO DeliveryTests.Actual
    FROM Delivery.OrderDestinations;

  SELECT TOP(0) *
    INTO DeliveryTests.Expected
    FROM DeliveryTests.Actual;

  INSERT INTO DeliveryTests.Expected (OrderId, Location) 
     VALUES (5, geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326).ToString());

  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'DeliveryTests.Expected', 
                               'DeliveryTests.Actual';
END;
GO
```

Comment: 5 years after this post and this data type is still not supported :) https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/assertions/assertequalstable/  but thanks for the workaround, is either that or just ignore it when faking your data